# EnableWebMvc throws ServletException: Could not resolve view with name

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, static-html

Playing around with Spring Boot + MVC with static HTML pages, while noticed this thing:

Firstly, what I have:

Index controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/{path:[^\\.]+}/**")
    public String forward() {
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

The Html file is:`...\src\main\resources\static\index.html`

So when my main application class is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Everything works well and in default path: `localhost:8080\` I get `index.html` page content

But if I annotate Application class with `@EnableWebMvc`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I get exception: `javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index.html' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'`
But according to [this spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) it is a valid configuration.

Maybe someone can explain me why? Do I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [spring-boot's docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration)

> The auto-configuration adds the following features on top of Spring’s defaults:
>
> - Static `index.html` support.
>
> ...
>
> If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features, and you just want to add
>   additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view
>   controllers etc.) you can add your own `@Configuration` class of type
>   `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, but **without** `@EnableWebMvc`. If you wish to
>   provide custom instances of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`,
>   `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` or `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` you
>   can declare a `WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter` instance providing such
>   components.

So by adding `@EnableWebMvc` you just disable what spring-boot autoconfiguring for you. Namely static `index.html` support.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think when you choose to use spring boot you should use the default config of spring Boot. It means you just have to edit the file *application.properties*. Now if you use spring mvc, you have to provide your own servlet. So I think mixing up the to is not a good idea. Either you use spring Boot wiht no much config to do or you use spring mvc and you make all the necessary config.

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring Boot MVC structure, you should locate your html file in the `templates` folder. Then will be visible for Spring Boot

```
src\main\resources\templates\index.html
```

Comment: `By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext...`  while `templates` is needed for dynamic content.

Comment: But you can use thymeleaf which is basically a html with th attribues, and no need to be dynamic could be fully static