# Return HTML page from Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app setup as a REST api. I now also want to be able to serve simple HTML pages to the client, without the use on any template engine like Thymeleaf. I want access to the HTML pages to fall under the same security constraints setup by Spring Security with the use of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, already present in my app.

---

What I've tried is having a `Controller`:

```
@Controller
public class HtmlPageController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/some/path/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getTestPage() {
        return "test.html";
    }
}
```

and placing the `test.html` file in `/resources/test.html` or `/webapp/WEB-INF/test.html`.

Every time I try to access the page at `localhost:8080/some/path/test` a `404` is returned.

**How do I make this work?**

Comment: try  `return "test";`

Comment: If I do that, the server instead throws `Circular view path [test]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/some/path/test] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)`

Comment: try return "classpath:/test.html"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okey so apparently Spring Boot supports this without any additional configuration or controllers.

All I had to do was to place the HTML file in the correct directory `/resources/static/some/path/test.html` and it can be reached at `localhost:8080/some/path/test.html`.

In my attempts to change the directory from which the file is served I was unsuccessful. [It seems that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543549/enablewebmvc-throws-servletexception-could-not-resolve-view-with-name/41543718) providing a separate `@EnableWebMvc` (needed for configuring the resource handlers) breaks the Spring Boot configuration. But I can live with using the default `/static` directory.

Comment: Your recommendation pointed me to the right solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your html, js and css files should be under the src/main/resources/static directory. and your return statement you can try removing .html.

```
@RestController
public class HtmlPageController {
    @GetMapping("/some/path/test")
    public String getTestPage() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do that, the server instead throws `Circular view path [test]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/some/path/test] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)`

Comment: replace @ Controller with @ RestController and add the thymeleaf dependency.

Comment: The question specifically states that I don't want to use any template engine like Thymeleaf.

Comment: @RestContoller will do . No need to add any thymeleaf dependency

Comment: No it won't. `@RestController` is the same as annotating the method with `@ResponseBody`, which then will return the string "test" in the response body.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Spring MVC mecanism that exists to provide static resources.

In the config class, overide this method :

```java
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("some/path/*.html")
        .addResourceLocations("/static/");
}
```

And place your html files in the `src/main/webapp/static/` folder.

If you request `some/path/test.html` (note the `.html`), it will return the test.html file located in `static` folder.

You can obviously use a different folder or a more sofiticated directory structure.

This way you don't have to create a controller. Note that your config class should implements `WebMvcConfigurer`.

Comment: what do you mean by config class? Where should I put the override method actually?

Answer (score 0):

See [tutotrial example](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-mvc-forms-jsp/src/main/java/com/baeldung/springmvcforms/configuration/ApplicationConfiguration.java) how to define html view in Spring MVC configuration

> ```
> @Bean
> public InternalResourceViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
>     InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
>     bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
>     bean.setSuffix(".html");
>     bean.setOrder(2);
>     return bean;
> }
> ```

- setOrder is set to 2 because it include also JSP support in example

Also you need to change to return without `.html` suffix

```
return "test.html";
```